# How to apply the "retrieve_password_message" filter?

Tags: filters, wp-mail, password

I would like to change the body of the password reset email that WP sends out with something more friendly.

I am trying to use the ["retrieve_password_message"](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_message/) filter but I am messing it up.

Can someone kindly post a sample code?

Answer (score 9):

the given answers have good intentions. But are not good. There are more parameters to the filter function call, 4 to be exact.

this worked for me for the message (i wanted to replace username with user email)

note we have a multi site page. You might want to replace network_site_url with `get_site_url()`

typically in your `functions.php` of your wordpress stheme:

```
add_filter("retrieve_password_message", "mapp_custom_password_reset", 99, 4);

function mapp_custom_password_reset($message, $key, $user_login, $user_data )    {

  $message = "Someone has requested a password reset for the following account:

" . sprintf(__('%s'), $user_data->user_email) . "

If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.

To reset your password, visit the following address:

" .  '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n" . "

If you have any further issues, please email us to help@myapp.com

The Myapp Team";


  return $message;

}
```

bonus: change email title / subject

```
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_title',
  function( $title )
  {
    $title = __( 'Password reset for myapp.org' );
    return $title;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought that this snippet of code may be helpful for anyone looking to customize the reset password email.

```
//* Password reset activation E-mail -> Body
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'wpse_retrieve_password_message', 10, 2 );
function wpse_retrieve_password_message( $message, $key ){
    $user_data = '';
    // If no value is posted, return false
    if( ! isset( $_POST['user_login'] )  ){
            return '';
    }
    // Fetch user information from user_login
    if ( strpos( $_POST['user_login'], '@' ) ) {

        $user_data = get_user_by( 'email', trim( $_POST['user_login'] ) );
    } else {
        $login = trim($_POST['user_login']);
        $user_data = get_user_by('login', $login);
    }
    if( ! $user_data  ){
        return '';
    }
    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;
    $user_email = $user_data->user_email;
    // Setting up message for retrieve password
    $message = "Looks like you want to reset your password!\n\n";
    $message .= "Please click on this link:\n";
    $message .= '<a href="';
    $message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login');
    $message .= '">"';
    $message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login');
    $message .= '"</a>\n\n"';
    $message .= 'Kind Regards,<br/>Dream Team';
    // Return completed message for retrieve password
    return $message;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check `$_POST` data to get user_login. You already have `user_login` in the hook parameter. Use 3 parameter instead of 2. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_message/

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but I really wanted to give @Toskan's answer a chance to rise to the top - it is a much better answer and uses the data available from the filter already instead of reconstructing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter("retrieve_password_message", "your_custom_message", 99, 2);

  function your_custom_message($message, $key)    {

  $message = "your_custom_message";

  return $message;

}
```

This is an example of usage of 'retrieve_password_message' filter hook.

This is to override the email body which someone gets while retrieving the password.

Comment: Please note: I have not tested it.

Comment: Please **explain** what it does.

Comment: Hi thanks for the input :-)   Could you please add the code for the reset password link.

Comment: @toscho, I have updated the answer with explanation.

Comment: @William, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @WisdmLabs The password reset link is missing from your snippet.  http://exmple.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key={ the key } &login={ the username }    :-)