# Right practice to edit WP reset password email

Tags: login, email, password

Since I'm pretty new to WordPress, I would like to know what is the right way to edit the WP reset password email. I would like to change the message.

I see that I need to edit the `retrieve_password_message` filter but I cannot understand if I can change the `wp-login.php` file.

What will happen in case of WP update? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The filter is there so you don't need to edit `wp-login.php`, simply use [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

Put something like

```
function change_password_reset_mail_body($message, $key, $user_login, $user_data) {
    return "click here: " . network_site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user_login ), 'login' );
}

add_filter("retrieve_password_message", "change_password_reset_mail_body", 10, 4)
```

In your theme's functions.php.

Comment: So can I add that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161001/133892 in function.php?

Comment: Yes. And you can adapt the message as you wish. I'd recommend getting the four variables directly into the function (see my answer) so you don't need to fetch the user data yourself. You'll also not need the additional security checks, WP takes care of that for you, but they won't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your other question ("what will happen with update"), any changes to WP 'core' functions will disappear with an WP update.

That's why looking at the source code for 'add_filter' opportunities is the best way to change how WP core functions behave.